# Creating bar plot with values corresponding to latest date of multiple time-series in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series, bar-chart

I have a dataframe, the first column of which are dates and the rest are values. The structure of the dataframe takes the following form:

```
Data <- data.frame(Date = c("2017-06-30","2017-06-29","2017-06-28","2017-06-27"), 
                   TS1 = c(1,2,3,4), TS2 = c(5,6,7,8), TS3 =c(9,10,11,12))
```

Is there a way to make a bar chart with the last date (in this case `2017-06-30`) on the x-axis along with the corresponding values of `TS1`, `TS2` and `TS3` (or `4,8,12`) on the y-axis?

Ideally, the solution would be in base-R, but any other way is also fine!

Comment: `barplot(t(Data[,2:4]), col=c("red","lightblue","gray"), 
        beside = T, las=3, names.arg=Data[,1], las=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up my comment:

```
barplot(t(Data[,2:4]), col=c("red","lightblue","gray"), 
    beside = T, las=3, 
    names.arg=Data[order(as.Date(as.character(Data[,1]), "%Y-%m-%d")),1], las=1)
```

[image]

If you only want the last time entry:

```
barplot(t(Data[nrow(Data),2:4]), col=c("red","lightblue","gray"), 
    beside = T, las=3, 
    names.arg=Data[order(as.Date(as.character(Data[,1]), "%Y-%m-%d")),1][nrow(Data)],las=1)
```

[image]

*explanation:*

`las=1` at the end makes the labels to be horizontal.

`order(as.Date(as.character(Data[,1]), "%Y-%m-%d")),1` this will give the ordered index of dates in the first column that we use to take the sorted labels for plotting.

`nrow(Data)` in the first line and third line point to the last entry.

`beside=T` makes them to be plotted in a group.

## Update:

***Answering OP's question in the comments:*** *"Is there an easy way to display the time-series name (TS1, TS2, TS3 in this example) below each bar instead of the date for the whole axis as well as the values above the bars?"*

You can define your axes as you wish. Below is an example that addresses your need:

```
barplot(t(Data[nrow(Data),2:4]), col=c("red","lightblue","gray"), 
        beside = T, axes=FALSE, xaxt="n") #plot with no axis
axis(2,0:12,las=2)    #y-axis
axis(1,2.5,line=2, las=1,
     labels =Data[order(as.Date(as.character(Data[,1]), "%Y-%m-%d")),1][nrow(Data)]) #x-axis with the date as the label in the second(3rd) line
axis(1,1:3+0.5,line=0, las=1,
     labels =colnames(Data[2:ncol(Data)])) #x-axis with time series names
text(x = 1:3+0.5, y = Data[nrow(Data),2:4], label = Data[nrow(Data),2:4], 
 pos = 3, cex = 0.8, col = "red", xpd=TRUE) # add the values as text to the plot
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! A very clear and straight-forward solution! Is there an easy way to display the time-series name (TS1, TS2, TS3 in this example) below each bar instead of the date for the whole axis as well as the values above the bars? Thank you again! c.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for the tip, will do that! May I ask a last question: Why do the values in the above graph not match the corresponding date? I just realised that 4-8-12 are attributable to 2017-06-27, if I am not mistaken...

Comment: @cthulhukk read your question again. That's what you wanted. If you want `1, 5, 9` then replace `t(Data[nrow(Data),2:4])` with `t(Data[order(as.Date(as.character(Data[,1]), "%Y-%m-%d")),2:ncol(Data)][nrow(Data)]))`.

Answer (score 2):

For the last date 2017-06-30 you can do (step by step):

```
Data <- data.frame(
Date = c("2017-06-30","2017-06-29","2017-06-28","2017-06-27"),
TS1 = c(1,2,3,4),
TS2 = c(5,6,7,8),
TS3 = c(9,10,11,12))
Data$Date<-as.Date(Data$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
Data<-Data[order(Data$Date),]
last_row<-Data[nrow(Data),]
p<-barplot(t(last_row[2:4]), beside=T, names.arg = colnames(last_row)[2:4])
mtext(side=1, text=last_row$Date, line=2.5)
text(y=t(last_row[2:4])+0.8, x=p, pos=1,labels=last_row[2:4], xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there an easy way to display the time-series name (TS1, TS2, TS3 in this example) below each bar instead of the date for the whole axis as well as the values above the bars? Thank you again! c.

Comment: I adjusted the answer accordingly

Comment: Don't you think the answer is wrong? Because you also sorted the values while OP wants the values of last row with the last date.

Comment: Its says for the date 2017-06-30 aka the last date, that's what I went along with and the data for that date is 1,5,9. Did I get it right ?

Comment: @Masoud: Very attentive, but in fact, the dates are in ascending order in the original file, so the solution is just perfect. Thank you, @Patrik_P!

Comment: @cthulhukk if the answer is correct, it should be accepted so the question is completed

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `ggplot2`

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

df1 <- melt(Data, "Date")

g1 <- ggplot(subset(df1, Date>=as.Date("2017-06-30")), aes(x=Date, y=value))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]